# Order of the characters in character set

Tags: c++, c

Is it guarantees by the standard the order of the characters? Can i count that '1' symbol are followed in the character set table by the '2' symbol, for example? Or is it platform-specific?

Answer (score 7):

The C standard from 1999 says this about the character sets:

> Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following members:
>   the 26 uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>   ...
>   the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet
>   ...
>   the 10 decimal digits
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>   the following 29 graphic characters
>   ...
>   In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

Comment: So it guarantees only the order of decimal digits?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov Yes. For C++ the same is true; see §2.3/3 of the C++11 Standard.

Answer (score 5):

The standard calls for numeric chars to be sequential, and indeed for all platforms I'm aware of '0' through '9' are, in fact, ordered and sequential. The same can NOT be said about alphabets in general. I point you to any of the [EBCDIC](http://natural-innovations.com/computing/asciiebcdic.html) platforms (AS/400, OS390, etc) for samples where this is most definitely not the case.

I.e. you can reliable do this:

```
for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++)
```

but you can NOT reliable do this:

```
for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
```

and expect the latter to sling through 26 iterations. It will be platform dependent.

Note: It is NOT specified in the standard that order outside of the digits (which are both ordered  and sequential) is guaranteed. Still, all platforms i've worked on (and that is a *big* number) exhibit consistent order properties even to alphabets, but only similar case. I.e. 'a' is always "less than" 'z'. But just like a bad penny, then comes back in EBCDIC platforms. For standard platforms 'A' is always less than 'z', but not in EBCDIC.

Bottom line: except for digit chars, you can't reliably assume near-*anything* about order or sequence and still maintain pure platform independence.

Comment: +1 for EBCDIC. This changes the approach to process of characters, where man uses the comparison of character numeric values... It won't work on all platforms

Comment: +1 Good answer. If course, for sort order, the user's locale settings trump all of this.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, dictionary sorting, language, accent sensitivity etc, all come into play at that point. I love asking the question, though and to this day it never gets old; Q: Why is the alphabet in that order? A: Sometimes.. it isn't =)